# Bring DisplayObject on top in DataGroup

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have `DataGroup` with custom item renderers, which can partly overlap each other. I have possibility to select these items. And I want selected item to be above others in the datagroup. But since `DataGroup` sets `childIndexes` (from left to right) to its children and we cannot change `childIndex` of items explicitly, selected item is above all items to the left and under all items to the right. So, what is the way to place selected item above others? I thought of using `PopUpAnchor`, but may be other solutions exist. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ItemRenderer's `depth` property to achieve this. Just set it to `0` when the renderer is not selected and set it to `1` when it is.

Christophe Coenraets wrote a very clear article (with example) on this. No need for me to add anything to that.

http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/01/cool-itemrenderers-made-easy-in-flex-4/

The first example is the one you want. This example uses the 'hovered' state instead of 'selected', but the idea is the same.